# copying files from unix to windows?

Tags: networking, windows, file-transfer

Is there any way to automate the process of copying the files between windows and unix
without doing it manually, using tools such as `winscp`.

I need to copy files from unix to windows such by executing some commands in windows. I goolged it and found these tools that can do this.

```
ftp
sftp
scp
pscp
winscp console.
```

**EDIT** : Can I get something using `pscp` because I just found out that `ftp` is not enable in my servers.

Please suggest a way of doing it and I need to run whatever script/command in windows only for copying the unix files.

**EDIT 2** : Getting this error in `winscp` console for `sftp` :

```
winscp> get abc.sh c:\
abc.sh                    |          0 KiB |    0.0 KiB/s | binary |   0%
Can't create file 'c:\abc.sh'.
System Error.  Code: 2.
The system cannot find the file specified
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all:
```

Comment: Regarding your edit 2: You may not have permission to create C:\abc.sh on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `WinSCP` script for this  [Here](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) you have some good piece of documentation on how to do this. Example script :

```
# Automatically abort script on errors
option batch abort
# Disable overwrite confirmations that conflict with the previous
option confirm off
# Connect using a password
# open sftp://user:password@example.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
# Connect
open sftp://user@example.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
# Change remote directory
cd /home/user
# Force binary mode transfer
option transfer binary
# Download file to the local directory d:\
get examplefile.txt d:\
# Disconnect
close
# Connect as a different user
open user2@example.com
# Change the remote directory
cd /home/user2
# Upload the file to current working directory
put d:\examplefile.txt 
# Disconnect
close
# Exit WinSCP
exit
```

Then save it to `example.txt` and use this command :

`winscp.exe /console /script=example.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to automate the process but the at the same time you say you want to run some commands. Other answers contain some command but if you want to have automation, checking out [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) might be worth a try. It allows not only unidirectional syncing but also provides a way to keep 2 directories in sync on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions... One way impacts how you'll approach it is where it should be initiated from.

From the Unix device, you should be able to mount a Windows file share and handle it like keeping local files synchronized. (Filenames with characters that Windows dislike might complicate it...)

You can also share the drive and mount it using NFS on Windows (It is in Services for Unix on XP, and an optional component in Vista and newer (might need specific editions, some alternatives are also available)). (Samba can also be used for a Windows file share if you do not want to install the NFS client on Windows)

Once that is set up, you can use tools like Unison and Rsync (or `cp` for simple cases) (if you do it from the Unix side) or SyncToy or similar tools (for the Windows side) as you would for local files.

scp (and the PuTTY-bundled equivalent `pscp` might be easier to secure, but need SSH keys set up to work automatically). `curl` also supports SCP and SFTP (mainly for fetching files) and might be useful for several other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider also `rsync`. There are many windows ports.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Samba` as `file sharing`.When you setup it, you can automate it via `shell script` and `crontab`.